# Memory Usage Test

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, xcode4

I am trying to see how much real memory my application is using. My application only uses the acceleometer for input, but when I click "Profile" in xcode 4 everything runs smoothly until my application starts up.  The accelerometer doesn't work correctly. My device only supports landscape right and when I tilt the device up the ball moves up, but if I tilt it any other way the ball doesn't move.

When I just build and run the game it works perfectly.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    #define kFilteringFactor 0.1f
    UIAccelerationValue rollingX, rollingY;

    rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

    rollingY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

    float accelX = acceleration.x - rollingX;
    float accelY = acceleration.y - rollingY;

    b2Vec2 gravity(-accelY * 3, accelX * 3);
    _world->SetGravity(gravity);
}
```

Any ideas?

Also this is completely different, but I'm using cocos2d to build my application and I've added a ball sprite. I can't change the ball sprite... I've removed the original image from the resources folder and added a different one with the same name but the image never changes.

Anyone know why?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean my accelerometer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean it stops working properly when profiling then yes, that will happen!

Profiling adds a large overhead to your code and accelerometer handler wants to happen regularly and often - something profiling stops!

I wouldn't worry about it if it works fine in a normal build.

---

And the ball sprite might just be cached on the device - have you tried both deleting the app from your iPhone and cleaning and rebuilding it in XCode?

Comment: ok oh cool, I guess I'll add touch to see how much memory i am using.  Also, yes I have tried that several times. I can even completely remove the ball image and the app still uses it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cocos2d to build my application and I've added a ball sprite. I can't change the ball sprite... I've removed the original image from the resources folder and added a different one with the same name but the image never changes.

---

To fix this problem, delete the application from your device or simulator, in XCode, go to Product ---> Clean, then build/run.